# When API site goes offline, please return a JSON , instead of Stack Overflow alike offline HTML page

Tags: feature-request, api, json

I've just noticed that my API queries are failing in JSON parsing, because of API Site shows offline HTML Page.

I wish it would return a valid JSON response, instead of HTML Page.

Comment: hmm..... needs a bump?

Comment: The image/screenshot is gone and not archived anywhere.  Please edit in the correct image.

Answer (score 5):

While this *would* indeed be ideal for planned outages, your code and/or libraries & dependencies should be able to handle this elegantly, lest you get bitten by the unplanned outages.

Comment: shouldn't you just be able to check the response code?

Comment: Exactly.  That, and set a reasonable timeout for the request.  No reason to go crazy on the server side.

Comment: @carson - jsonp implementations have a very limited and platform inconsistent ability to respond to non-200 responses, basically making a non-200 response a black hole leaving an ambiguous and artificial timeout the only option.